# Access mulitple Datasource with JdbcTemplate results in error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have two projects one with DAO classes and Model  and another with Rest Controller

Project  A : DAO Classes + Model

Project B : Rest Controller

---

Project A

application.properties:

```
spring.abcDatasource.url=
spring.abcDatasource.username=
spring.abcDatasource.password=
spring.abcDatasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


spring.xyzDatasource.url=
spring.xyzDatasource.username=
spring.xyzDatasource.password=
spring.xyzDatasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

DBConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "abcDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.abcDatasource")
    public DataSource abcDS() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "abcJdbc")
    public JdbcTemplate abcJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("abcDS") DataSource abcDS) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(abcDS);
    }

    @Bean(name = "xyzDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.xyzDatasource")
    public DataSource xyzDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xyzJdbc")
    public JdbcTemplate ebsJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("xyzDS") DataSource xyzDatasource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(xyzDatasource);
    }


}
```

AlphaDAO.Java

```
@Repository
public class AlphaDAO{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("abcJdbc")
    private JdbcTemplate abcJdbc;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("xyzJdbc")
    private JdbcTemplate xyzJdbc;

    SqlParameterSource namedParameters;



    public Collection<Alpha> findAll(String owner){

        String sql =  "SELECT * from alpha where OWNER in (:owner)" ;

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(abcJdbc.getDataSource());


        namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("owner", owner);


        List<Alpha> list  = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql,namedParameters,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Alpha.class));

        return list;
    }
```

Project B Rest Controller :

AlphaServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AlphaServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(AlphaServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AlphaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

AlphaServiceController.java

```
@RestController
public class AlphaServiceController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlphaServiceController.class);

    @Autowired
    AlphaDAO dao;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/alpha")
    public Collection<Alpha> index(@RequestBody String owner) {
        return dao.findAll(owner);
    }
```

If I try to run the rest controller I am  getting the error saying

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field dao in com.xyz.web.wip.AlphaService.AlphaServiceController required a bean of type 'com.xyz.comp.wip.alphaComp.dao.AlphaDAO' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xyz.comp.wip.alphaComp.dao.AlphaDAO' in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AlphaDao` class doesnt make much sense, you are trying to autowire two fields but you still have a constructor.
Spring cant build the object because there is no qualifier on the constructor.
You can either do constructor injection or field injection but you shouldn’t use both.
I would recommend using constructor injection.

```
@Repository
public class AlphaDAO{

    private final JdbcTemplate abcJdbc;
    private final JdbcTemplate xyzJdbc;

    @Autowired
    public AlphaDAO(
          @Qualifier("abcJdbc") JdbcTemplate abcJdbc, 
          @Qualifier("xyzJdbc") JdbcTemplate xyzJdbc){
        this.abcJdbc = abcJdbc;
        this.xyzJdbc = xyzJdbc;
    }
```

Also remove your `@Bean` method from the controller.

Comment: I am getting the  same error after making these changes

Answer (score 0):

Since the DAO classes and Rest Controller is in different packages. Added scanBasePackages to @SpringBootApplication annotation with one level up worked fine.

```
AlphaServiceApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.xyz" })
```